# Get total number of rows from subquery?

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have a query like

```
SELECT row1, row2
FROM (
    SELECT b.row21, COUNT(b.row21) AS hits
    FROM table2 AS b
    WHERE b.row22 = 'foo' OR b.row22 = 'bar'
    GROUP BY b.row21
    HAVING hits = 2
) AS b
INNER JOIN table1 AS a ON (b.row21 = a.row1)
WHERE row2 = 123
LIMIT 10
```

Now clearly, the result is limited first by an additional `WHERE` and finally by `LIMIT`.

So how would I retrieve the amount of rows returned by the subquery without needing to execute it seperately?

Comment: You should ask your self how it should be displayed? I mean the subquery count would be grouped function and the row1, row2 are single function. logically, where do you expect it to be displayed?

Comment: @7alhashmi I'm displaying the results on a website. So I want a count of total results with it while offering pages through `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL using variables:

```
SELECT row1, row2, @rn as numrows
FROM (
    SELECT b.row21, COUNT(b.row21) AS hits, @rn := @rn + 1
    FROM table2 b cross join
         (select @rn := 0) const
    WHERE b.row22 = 'foo' OR b.row22 = 'bar'
    GROUP BY b.row21
    HAVING hits = 2
) AS b
INNER JOIN table1 AS a ON (b.row21 = a.row1)
WHERE row2 = 123
LIMIT 10;
```

You run the risk that MySQL *could* rewrite the query in a very different way, that might avoid the generation of certain rows.  Some SQL compilers are smart enough to do this.  I don't think MySQL is that smart.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast . . . The cross join is used to define the initial value of the variable `@rn`.

Comment: Got it and it works, although the overall statement is now 10 to 20 times slower... Is there any way to speed that up?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast . . . I don't know why adding the variable would have that effect.  You need to do an `explain`, with and without the code, to see if the query plan changed.  Actually, one difference is that the original code did not actually have to complete the subquery to return 10 rows.  However, this version does have to run the entire subquery.

Comment: `explain` shows two more `derived` selects, one of type `system` and one of type `null` with extra `no tables used`. Everything else stayed the same.

Comment: Alright nevermind, there probably was something else using up resources coincidentally...